# Form array Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I'm having a hard time integrating this form with the html. can you help me? I've tried in some ways but I couldn't connect because I'm using FormArray.
I made the form but to access the controls in the html is very complicated.
I need it to be form Array, because this will have several arrays with categories.
I need it to be form Array, because this will have several arrays with categories.

```js
Form in Component TS

  testeForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    feedstock: this.fb.array([
      this.addFeedStockArray()
    ])
  });
  
  
    addFeedStockArray(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      category: "",
      position: "",
      feedstockOptions: this.fb.array([
        this.addFeedStockOptions()
      ]),
   })
 }
  
  
    addFeedStockOptions(): FormGroup {
     return this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      code: '',
      price: {
        amount: '',
        currency: ['BRL'],
      }
    })
  }
  
  
  addfeedStockClick(): void {
    (<FormArray>this.testeForm.get('feedstock')).push(this.addFeedStockOptions());
  }
```

```html
              <div [formGroup]="testeForm" style="margin-left: 40px">
                <div class="second-column row" formArrayName="feedstock" >
                  <div class="row" [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let feedstock of feedstock.get('feedstockOptions')?.controls; let i = index">
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label>
                          NOME:
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-control"
                              placeholder="--" formControlName="name" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label>
                          CÓDIGO:
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-control"
                              placeholder="--" formControlName="code">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label>
                          PREÇO:
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-control"
                              currencyMask
                              [options]="{ prefix: 'R$ ', thousands: '.', decimal: ',', align:'left'}"
                              min="0"
                              placeholder="R$" formControlName="price" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col">
                      <i class="material-icons close-category"  style="margin-top: 40px" (click)="removefeedStockClick(i)" >
                        close
                      </i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a minimal change to see if it fixes your issue

```
<div [formGroup]="testeForm" style="margin-left: 40px">
  <div class="second-column row" formArrayName="feedstock" >
    <ng-container *ngFor="let feedstock of feedstock.get('feedstockOptions')?.controls; let i = index">
      <div class="row" [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="form-group col">
          <label>NOME:</label>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="--" formControlName="name" >
         </div>
      </div>
      ......
    </ng-container>
```

Used an ng-container to wrap the *ngFor directive

UPDATE

After seeing the complete code, realized there is one larger mistake:
There are 2 levels of FormArray and need to be accessed like that.

```
<div [formGroup]="testeForm" style="margin-left: 40px">
  <div class="second-column row" formArrayName="feedstock" >
    <ng-container *ngFor="let fcFeedStock of testeForm.get('feedstock')?.controls; let i = index">
      <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
        <ng-container formArrayName="feedstockOptions">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let feedstockOption of fcFeedStock.get('feedstockOptions')?.controls; let j = index">
            <div class="row" [formGroupName]="j">
              <div class="form-group col">
                <label>NOME:</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="--" formControlName="name" >
              </div>
            </div>
        ......
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

UPDATE 2:

Showing price > amount

As price is a FormGroup, and amount is a FormControl:

```
 ...
 <div class="row" [formGroupName]="i">
    <div class="form-group col">
      <label>NOME:</label>
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="--" formControlName="name" >
     </div>
     <div formGroupName="price">
       <input formControlName="amount">
     </div>
  </div>
  ...
```

How to add one new element to the array:

The issue is you are confusing between the 2 FormArrays 'feedstock' and 'feedstockOptions'.

```
// This function should do feedstock.push(this.addFeedStockArray())
addfeedStockClick(): void {
  (<FormArray>this.testForm.get('feedstock')).push(this.addFeedStockArray());
}
```

For adding to feedstockOptions, you first need the index of the feedstock, access it's feedstockOptions, and then push to it:

```
(<FormArray>(<FormArray>this.testForm.get('feedstock')).at(index).get('feedstockOptions')).push(this.addFeedStockOptions());
```

or if you can manage to directly access the fcFeedstock, the line of code would simplify to:

```
(<FormArray>fcFeedstock.get('feedstockOptions')).push(this.addFeedStockOptions())
```

Comment: Hi, I made some tweaks to fit my code and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.
Two more questions, how do I access amount? in price: {
amount: "",
currency: '' }
Last doubt, I'm trying to add a new array like this,
addfeedStockClick(): void {
     (<FormArray>this.testForm.get('feedstock')).push(this.addFeedStockOptions());
   }

however it is taking the values from the old array.

Comment: In HTML /// <div class="divide-section"> <div class="first-column" [formGroup]="testeForm"><div class="header-section options" (click)="addfeedStockClick()"><span>ADD </span> 
<i class="material-icons">
add
</i>
</div>
</div>

<div [formGroup]="testeForm" style="margin-left: 40px">
<div class="second-column row" formArrayName="feedstock" >
 <ng-container *ngFor="let fcFeedStock of testeForm.get('feedstock')?.controls; let i = index"><ng-container [formGroupName]="i"><div class="form-group"> ///

Comment: I have updated the answer with explanation to suit your scenario.